# Customize the date format in Windows 10 other than suggestions

Tags: date, format, customization, region

I use Windows 10. I live in Switzerland, yet I prefer my Windows in English. My Regional format is set to "English (Switzerland)". Now, in Switzerland, the common date format would be 25.05.2024 (dd.mm.yyyy). The default format is listed as 25/04/2024, so I would like to change that. I click on "Change data formats", yet the desired option is not available.
Is there a way to set my desired format? I'm aware that I can do it within Excel or other applications, but don't want to customize format all the cells every time I want to write the date. I would like it to be default, in Windows 10.
[My choices screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6AB9.png)
I don't understand why they offer a "customization", yet all I can do is pick between two formats.

I tried English (United States) and English (United Kingdom) which gave me other options, but never as desired. One was 2.3.24, but that's not how we would use it. In this case it would need the zeros: 02.03.2024.